# Manga where mc leaves party changes appearance and name

Tags: story-identification, manga

He is with a girl called the sword goddess, they are the only 2 members in their party and he is 'useless'. He gets fed up of being treated awfully and so he leaves changes his name to Flint and dyes his hair red. Then joins the guild as a lower rank and the girl he left ,who I believe was also his girlfriend, looks for him for ages and cries often as she can't find him. This is all I remember, any help is much appreciated :)!

Comment: Was it an animated film, a book, a comic strip, what year was it made in? Take a look at our [story ID checklist](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and see if it jogs your memory. You can then [edit] to add details.

Comment: It's a Japanese manga. She's his childhood friend, not girlfriend. Unfortunately, there's (at least) two of them with the same basic premise. I'm not getting any matches for "flint" but I think only one of them would involve hair dye.

Comment: Guess I was wrong; she was his girlfriend. Or he thought they were going out. The other manga I mentioned is "Tsuihou no Kenja, Sekai wo Shiru: Osanajimi Yuusha no Atsuryoku kara Nigete Jiyuu ni Natta Ore", which has the same opening of "sword genius girl bullies childhood friend male protagonist into quitting and regrets it"

Answer (score 6):

This is *[A Sword Master Childhood Friend Power Harassed Me Harshly, So I Broke off Our Relationship and Make a Fresh Start at the Frontier as a Magic Swordsman](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/kensei-no-osananajimi-ga-pawahara-de-ore-ni-tsuraku-ataru-no-de-zetsuen-shite-henkyou-de-makenshi-toshite-denaosu-koto-ni-shita)*

> The harassment from Alfine ー his girlfriend and childhood friend ー who is the same age, grew up with him, and became adventurers together, is painful. She is a peerless beauty known as the "Flawless Sword Goddess" and has the title "Sword Master." Her achievements were recognized by the kingdom as a knight and gained a noble title. On the other hand, he is treated as Alfine’s verbally abused accessory and suffers from her harsh harassment

His childhood friend and girlfriend abuses him, so he ends up running away. He cuts his hair, dyes in red, and changes his name to Flint (A reviewer uses the name "Flick", which I'm guessing is just an alternate possibility for the original Japanese).

She does try to find him and cries about losing him, regretting his decision to leave almost immediately.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much 